# Don't seen jspTrack div on jsscrollpane

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using `jscrollPane` jQuery plugin. When I add:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myDiv-1').jScrollPane();
});
```

The code works, but when I do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myDiv-1 ').jScrollPane();
    $('#myDiv-2 ').jScrollPane();
});
```

`myDiv-1` is OK, but I can not get `jspTrack` div on `myDiv-2`. So, don't working. What's my problem?

Comment: Why the spaces in the id name? That isn't valid. Also, please post a fiddle with an example because this depends on your HTML and CSS. I've done this hundred of times and it works well so the problem is not with jscrollpane.

Comment: Spaces nevermind on this problem. Edited.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle with your content or give us a link to your demo directly?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong with spaces or your code. You may try:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myDiv-1, #myDiv-2').jScrollPane();
});
```

Or you may try adding both divs a class named *scroll-pane* and match multiple elements like;

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/less_basic.html

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

But I doubt that those examples will work/change anything. Could you post some of your code?